# For ideal $I$, If $rI = I$ what is $r$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

For a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, we have $aN = N$, then it means $a \in N$, and a similar conclusion holds in a field with multiplication. In both cases, it is due to the existence of an inverse. When working with quotient groups, this seems to be very applicable in that we can conclude $a-b \in N$ from $a+N = b+N$.

> However, in a commutative ring $R$ with unity, let $I$ be an ideal in $R$, and $r \in R$, if we have $rI = I$, can we conclude anything?

In this case, we don't have inverses, so I'm a little unsure what to say. When $r$ is a unit, this is of course true, but I'm not sure if $rI =I$ necessarily implies that $r$ is a unit, and whether there is something to say about $r$ in general.

Comment: One always has $rI \subseteq I$ by the definition of an ideal. So, one only needs to ask whether $I \subseteq rI$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Yeah of course, but when is that true?

Comment: This is quite hard to answer for the situation can vary. Note that if $R$ is commutative and has $1$, then any unit $u$ shall satisfy $uI=I$. If $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $I=2\mathbb{Z}$, then the units $\{1,-1\}$ are all the elements $r$ s.t. $rI=I$. Another extreme is $I=\{0\}$. Then any $x\in R$ shall satisfy $xI=I$.

Comment: If $I$ is finitely generated and $R$ is an integral domain, one version of Nakayama's Lemma implies that $r$ is a unit.  On the other hand, if $I$ is generated by an idempotent  $r$, of course $I=rI$.

Comment: @AllenBell Thank you for the comments. Would you mind writing this as an answer and also give examples of when $r$ is not necessarily a unit?

Comment: If you only have $rI \subset I$ then we have a $\textit{left sided ideal}$. If in addition $Ir \subset I$ then $I$ is an ideal in $R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I$ be a nonzero ideal of $R$, and let $r\in R$.  As noted by the OP, if $r$ is a unit, then $rI=I$.  The converse result is true in some but not all cases.

We'll show $rI=I$ implies $r$ is a unit if (i) $R$ is a UFD or (ii) $I$ is finitely generated and has annihilator zero (e.g., $R$ is an integral domain).  To show (i) is true, let $i_0$ be a nonzero element of $I$ with shortest possible factorization.  If $r$ is not a unit, then $ri$ has a longer factorization than $i$ for any nonzero $i\in I$.  Thus $ri$ can never equal $i_0$ and so $rI\neq I$.  To show (ii) is true, we invoke Nakayama's Lemma.  This tells us that if $rI=I$ (and $I$ is finitely generated), there is an $s\in R$ with $(1-rs)I=0$.  If $I$ has zero annihilator, this implies $r$ is a unit.

More generally, we've shown that if $I$ is finitely generated, then $rI=I$ if and only if there is an $s\in R$ with $(1-rs)I=0$.
Such elements $r$ need not be units; if $I$ is not finitely generated, this criterion is no longer valid.  Here are a couple of examples.  First, let $R$ be the integers mod $6$.  If $I=\bar3 R$ and $r=\bar 3$, then $rI=I$, but $r$ is not a unit.  If $I=\bar2 R$ and $r=\bar 2$ or $r=\bar 4$, then $rI=I$, but $r$ is not a unit or an idempotent.

Next, consider $R=\mathbb{Z}+x\mathbb{Q}[x]$, which is clearly an integral domain.  Let $I=x\mathbb{Q}[x]$: this is an ideal of $R$.  If $r$ is any positive integer, $rI=I$, but if $r>1$, $r$ is not a unit.